# Is it possible to work with only one specific window (JS for exmple) instead of the usual 4 in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Sometimes I would like to be able to work on only one window at a time, for example when I'm focused only in JavaScript and I have a little monitor space, or when I'm working on some big HTML layout and there are lots of nested tags.

Is there an option or command which allow jsfiddle to show only one particular working area?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want with a javascript console. Here's an easy way to make all windows but the js part to magically disappear:

```
document.querySelector('.column.left .top').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('.column.right').style.display = 'none';
```

From here it's just messing around with the css. You can, for example, change the js part expand to full height:

```
document.querySelector('.column.left .bottom').style.height = '100%';
```

And to make it expand to full width:

```
document.querySelector('.column.left').style.width = '100%';
```